# Does there always exist a multiple keyhole avoiding finite number of points?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

Let's $C$ be a circle in $\mathbb C$. Let $z_1,\ldots,z_N$ be points in the region enclosed by $C$ ($C$ itself is not contained in that region). A multiple keyhole avoiding $z_1,\ldots,z_N$ is a shape of the form below.

[image]

The whole shape should not intersect itself (so it should be a simple closed curve), the small circle enclosing $z_i$ should be centered at $z_i$, all the small circles should have a same radius, the two line segments that form a corridor should be parallel, and all the segments deleted from $C$ should have the same length.

Does a multiple keyhole avoiding $z_1,\ldots,z_N$ always exist? It seems to exist when $N$ is small, but I'm not sure it will exist for arbitrary $N$.

I need to know the existence of such multiple keyhole to prove the residue formula in complex analysis. I'm reading Stein's "*Complex Analysis*" p. 77.

### Edit

I tried to prove this by mathematical induction. I assumed that it holds for $N$, and tried to prove that it also holds for $N+1$. But in the situation below, $N$ is $4$, and the new point is shown by the grey dot near the center. I don't think I can connect $C$ with a small circle centered at the grey dot in any way.

[image]

Comment: Short answer: yes, by induction.

Comment: I'm sure one can prove the residue formula without needing to construct such a contour.

Comment: @AnginaSeng How?

Comment: Here's another approach. Let $\delta>0$ be the minimum distance between any two points. Draw circles of radius $\delta/50$ around each point. Surely there is a 'broken line loop' path connecting these circles; make it and then erase parts of the circles to get your keyhole contour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Longer answer: Surely you can avoid one point, so the base case is satisfied.

Suppose you have a keyhole contour avoiding $k$ points. Introduce a new point $p_{k+1}$ to be avoided. We can "stretch" the outer circle $C$ to enclose all $k+1$ points if necessary. There is a minimum distance between $p_{k+1}$ and the other $p_i$, $1\leq i\leq k$. Call it $d>0$. Draw a keyhole of radius $d/50$ around $p$, and draw the straight lines connecting this keyhole to $C$ avoiding the other $k$ points.

Comment: I edited my question. Can you check it?